# Calculating the total quantity and matching it with stock table in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Its something like Online shopping website.
Here on `product_details.aspx` page, i have a quantity `textbox` where user enters the quantity of Product. What i have to do is, if user enters maximum no of quantity than available quantity in stock, then it must shows us the message that "Sorry, we have no more quantity available in Stock!". For that, i have written the following code.

```
if (e.CommandName == "AddCart")
        {
            var lblProID = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblProID")).Text;
            var lblProName = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblProName")).Text;
            var lblProPrice = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblProPrice")).Text;
            int i = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text); // Storing textbox value in "i"
            var SessionId = Session.SessionID;

            // Getting total Qty against selected Pro_ID
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(" SELECT SUM(Qty) AS Quantity FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Stock] where [Pro_ID] = '" + lblProID + "' ", con);
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            // Checking if Qty in stock is less then qty written in Textbox then....
            if (dt.Rows.Count < i)
            {
                lblQty.Text = "Sorry, we have no more quantity available in Stock!";
            }
            else
            {
                Session["Get_Pro_ID"] = lblProID;
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Cart_Tbl]  values('" + SessionId + "', '" + lblProID + "', '" + lblProName + "', '" + lblProPrice + "', '" + i + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Response.Redirect("cart.aspx");
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Stock table `Stock    [Stock_ID] ,[Pro_ID] ,[Warehouse_ID] ,[Qty] ,[Status]`

Products Table `Products    SELECT [Pro_ID]
      ,[Pro_Name]
      ,[Cmp_ID]
      ,[Cat_ID]
      ,[Code]
      ,[Serial_No]
      ,[Size]
      ,[Color]
      ,[Unit_Price]
      ,[FileName]
      ,[FilePath]`
This is product_details.aspx page image...

[image: product_details.aspx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your DataTable will always return 1 row, you can use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead since you are returning single row & column.

```
con.Open();
int TotalQuantity = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
if (TotalQuantity  < i)
```

Also, please note your query is open for [SQL Inject attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use Parameterized query instead.

If you wanna stick with your current approach(which IMHO is not required) then you can do this:-

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
adapter.Fill(dt);
int TotalQuantity = (int)dt.Rows[0]["Quantity"];
```

Comment: No sir... Same problem

Comment: @HamzaJaved - You should have `con.Open()` before executing the command. Also there is is no need of `ToString()`

Comment: ,,, Then what should i do

Comment: @HamzaJaved - Check my update (first query) you should open the connection before executing the command.

Comment: @HamzaJaved - Stick with first query for now. Debug and check what is the value of `TotalQuantity `

Comment: @HamzaJaved - Don't use `int.Parse`, please copy paste my first query as it is.

Comment: Sorry... let me cehck now again

Comment: @HamzaJaved - Have you debugged the code? What value you are getting from database?

Comment: I placed the break points, but it says, breakpoint not allowed

Comment: @HamzaJaved - Where you have placed? You should keep on the line of code, share screenshot.

Comment: @HamzaJaved - Definitely problem with you code buddy, probably sql not returning correct data. But trust me if you can't debug nobody can help you. My code is correct and will work if you execute it properly.

Comment: @HamzaJaved - Have you build the complete solution before adding breakpoint?

Comment: My problem solved..  I just clean and build the solution and restarted the visual studio.. Thanks @Rahul